# how to cancel authentication in AuthenticationSuccessHandler?

Tags: php, symfony

I made a child class that extends from DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler in order to add custom feature during the authentication process. I want to stop the authentication process if the criteria is not met. How do I do that?

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
    if(some_condition_applies){
        //if success, resume default flow
        return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess( $request, $token);
    }else{
        //how to fail the authentication here?
    }
}
```

Comment: `onAuthenticationSuccess` is called **after** the user is authenticated. SO i think you need a custom user provider.

Comment: I think so. After I've been looking through Symfony's default authentication provider, I realized it's the provider I have to make change rather than the successhandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AuthenticationSuccessHandler's main purpose is to do something AFTER the user has been authenticated. In other words it is too late to do anything about it.

You can create a custom authentication provider which handles all the authentication logic you require.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-authentication-provider

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, the new SimpleFormAuthenticator functionality in Symfony 2.4 may help you out: [How to Create a Custom Form Password Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html)

This is probably only applicable if your authentication mechanism is username/password based (not OAuth or something).

Additionally, you could potentially just implement the AdvancedUserInterface, and then return "false" from a method like "isEnabled" to prevent login ([Forbid Inactive Users](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#forbid-inactive-users)). The only disadvantage is that you only have access to data in your User class. If you need something beyond that, the above method should work (but is a little bit more work).

Cheers!